# Powershell. edit string make it camelCase and PascalCase

Tags: powershell

My goal is to know how this kind of text `$var1 = "my-name-is"` convert to camelCase`"myNameIs"`.
And this type `$var2 = "my_Name_is"`  convert to PascalCase`"MyNameIs"`

Have no idea how to do it

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: what I should do if I haven't tried something? because I have no Idea have to do that

Comment: I would start by finding some good PowerShell reference books and start reading. Posting questions that look like "do my homework/class exercise" is strongly discouraged by this community; we'll help if we see effort to solve it on your part.

Comment: I got it. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** solution, taking advantage of the ability to use [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) to perform dynamic replacements via the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```bash
# camelCase (separator char. in input string is "-")
# -> 'myNameIs'
"my-name-is" -replace '-(\p{L})', { $_.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() }

# PascalCase (separator char. in input string is "_")
# -> 'MyNameIs'
"my_Name_is" -replace '(?:^|_)(\p{L})', { $_.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() }
```

Note:

- `\p{L}` matches any Unicode character that is categorized as a *letter*, meaning that it doesn't just match ASCII-range (English) letters such as `e`, but also accented characters such as `è` - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories)
- To restrict matching to ASCII-range letters, use `[a-z]` (because PowerShell's operators are case-*insensitive* by default, this expression also matches *uppercase* letters).

**Windows PowerShell** solution:

Direct use of the underlying .NET APIs is required, because use of script blocks as `-replace`'s replacement operand aren't supported in this edition.

```bash
# camelCase
# -> 'myNameIs'
[regex]::Replace(
  "my-name-is", 
  '(?i)-(\p{L})', 
  { $args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() }
)

# PascalCase
# -> 'MyNameIs'
[regex]::Replace(
  "my_Name_is", 
  '(?i)(?:^|_)(\p{L})', 
  { $args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() }
)
```

Comment: could you help me. How I can get unique and alphabetical sorted string, for example "dasdas" -> "ads"   @mklement0

Comment: @seyshanbe: `-join ("dasdas".ToCharArray() | Sort-Object -Unique)`. In general, please don't ask follow-up questions in comments and instead create a _new_ question post.

Answer (score 11):

You might use the .NET [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase(String)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase) for this.

For **PascalCase** this is quiet straight forward:

```
$Text = $Var1 -Replace '[^0-9A-Z]', ' '
(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($Text) -Replace ' '
```

For **camelCase** there is a little more at stake:

```
$First, $Rest = $Var2 -Replace '[^0-9A-Z]', ' ' -Split ' ',2
$First.Tolower() + (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($Rest) -Replace ' '
```

### Explanation

```
'my_Name_is' -Replace '[^0-9A-Z]', ' '
```

Replaces any character that isn't Alphanumeric with a space (result: `my Name is`).
<sup>(Note that PowerShell is case insensitive by default)</sup>

```
'my Name is' -Split ' ',2
```

Splits the word (`'my'`) from the rest (`'Name is'`).

```
$First, $Rest = 'my', 'Name is'
```

Stores the first word in `$First` and the rest in `$Rest`.

```
$First.Tolower() + (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($Rest)
```

Puts the first word in lowercase and the rest in title case (result: `myName Is`)

```
'myName Is' -Replace ' '
```

Removes any spaces (result: `myNameIs`).

Comment: doesn't your "Replaces any character that isn't Alphanumeric" expression not be '[^0-9a-zA-Z]'? I think you're missing the lowercase characters and the comma may be seen as a literal character. Everything else: excellent answer!

Comment: @GerardV, you are correct about the comma (I have updated the answer for this) -thanks. For the lowercase, PowerShell is case insensitive by nature and therefore `A-Z` will capture both upper- and lowercase. For a case sensitive replace, you will need the `-CReplace` operator.

Answer (score 2):

This function will help you out!

```
$var1 = "my-name-is"

function ToCamelCase($str){
    
    $bits = @()
    foreach($token in $str.Split('-')) {
        $newBit = $token[0].ToString().ToUpper(), $token.TrimStart($token[0]) -join ''
        $bits +=$newBIt
    }
    $bits -join ''

}

PS> ToCamelCase $VAR1
MyNameIs
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert dashed string to Camel Case you can use one-liner:

```
$t.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + ((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($t.ToLower() -replace "-", " ")) -replace " ", "").Substring(1)
```